# Configuring sitecore sites

Tags: content-management-system, web-config, sitecore

Within the web.config we have the following:

```
<sites>

  <site name="shell" virtualFolder="/sitecore/shell" physicalFolder="/sitecore/shell" rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/home" language="en" database="core" domain="sitecore" loginPage="/sitecore/login" content="master" contentStartItem="/Home" enableWorkflow="true" enableAnalytics="false" xmlControlPage="/sitecore/shell/default.aspx" browserTitle="Sitecore" htmlCacheSize="2MB" registryCacheSize="3MB" viewStateCacheSize="200KB" xslCacheSize="5MB" />
  <site name="login" virtualFolder="/sitecore/login" physicalFolder="/sitecore/login" enableAnalytics="false" database="core" domain="sitecore" disableXmlControls="true" />
  <site name="admin" virtualFolder="/sitecore/admin" physicalFolder="/sitecore/admin" enableAnalytics="false" enableWorkflow="true" domain="sitecore" loginPage="/sitecore/admin/login.aspx" />
  <site name="service" virtualFolder="/sitecore/service" physicalFolder="/sitecore/service" />
  <site name="modules_shell" virtualFolder="/sitecore modules/shell" physicalFolder="/sitecore modules/shell" rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/home" language="en" database="core" domain="sitecore" content="master" enableAnalytics="false" enableWorkflow="true" />
  <site name="modules_website" virtualFolder="/sitecore modules/web" physicalFolder="/sitecore modules/web" rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/home" language="en" database="web" domain="extranet" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="true" />
  <site name="developer_default" hostName="developer05.poc" virtualFolder="" physicalFolder="/" rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/Partners/UK/" database="web" domain="extranet" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="true" htmlCacheSize="10MB" registryCacheSize="0" viewStateCacheSize="0" xslCacheSize="5MB" filteredItemsCacheSize="2MB" enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" enableDebugger="true" disableClientData="false" />
  <site name="scheduler" enableAnalytics="false" domain="sitecore" />
  <site name="system" enableAnalytics="false" domain="sitecore" />
  <site name="publisher" domain="sitecore" enableAnalytics="false" enableWorkflow="true" />
  <site name="unfunctioning_site_default" hostName="subdomain.developer05.poc" virtualFolder="" physicalFolder="/" rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/Partners/UK/SomeSite" database="web" domain="extranet" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="true" htmlCacheSize="10MB" registryCacheSize="0" viewStateCacheSize="0" xslCacheSize="5MB" filteredItemsCacheSize="2MB" enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" enableDebugger="true" disableClientData="false" />

</sites>
```

This works fine, if I add another site after the `publisher`, `system` and `scheduler` sites I get issues I was wondering if anyone knew why is it that I have to add them before?

The issue I get is:

> The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /default
>
> User Name: sitecore\Anonymous
>
> Site Name: scheduler
>
> If the page you are trying to display exists, please check that an appropriate prefix has been added to the IgnoreUrlPrefixes setting in the web.config.

Comment: Are you accessing the site in your browser via the host `developer05.poc`?

Comment: actually yes its subdomain.developer05.poc, improved the example above!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sitecore will utilize the first site that it can match, either by path or by host name. This is why the scheduler, system, and publisher sites are last, since they do not have any path or host name values. You can see from the message you get that Sitecore is matching on the scheduler site. Typically new sites would be added right after modules_website. Move yours there and you should be golden.

Comment: An addition: remember to add sites to the "publish:end" hint list, to insure that the cache is cleared for those sites as well

Answer (score 3):

The answer is as Techphoria says, but for further info, I recently blogged about Sitecore multi-site setups, inter-site links, and out-of-context link generation : http://blog.paulgeorge.co.uk/2011/05/01/sitecore-linkmanager-inside-out-muti-site-and-sub-site-setups/